# SSRS Reporting Services

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have been trying for SSRS 2008R2 reports access from my one of the server which are delpoyed on it (O.S windows 2008 R2 server) to my web
application which is hosted on another server  ..
  I tried by using reportviewer and by passing the server credentails.
I am getting an error :
 Unable to connect to the remote server
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond IPAddess:80

plzz can any one help me..

Answer (score 1):

Looks more a firewall port blocking problem to me.

Can you open the report server via `http://yourserver/reports` on the machine itself?
If so then check your firewall settings on the server. On default they block all incoming port in "domain", "public" and "private".

EDIT:

Checkout the screenshot for firewall settings (german, but english gui is the same location)
[image]

Comment: how to check ..can you tell me

Comment: Does your report server works if you open it on the machine itself?

Comment: I added a screenshot where to turn off or modify firewall

Comment: do i need to stop the firewall ...it is on

Comment: depends on your setup :) for testing just turn it off. later you can configure incoming connections and open specific ports (e.g. port 80 for http)